# Copy data from one database to another?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am upgrading a clients app to a newer version, the databases are close but slightly different. I need to figure out a way to transform and copy the data from one table in one database to another table in the new database. Oh geez :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO new_db.dbo.TableA
SELECT * FROM old_db.dbo.TableB
```

If the tables are the same, this is probably the easiest way.

Comment: Yes, that would be the simpliest approach.

Comment: How can we get data of database which is present in another connection string ?

Answer (score 4):

[SQL Server Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) (previously known as Data Transformation Services) is the way to go.

SQL Server Import and Export data wizard works for simple tasks pretty well.

Comment: It's shipped with SQL Server DVD.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Integration Services is going to be your best bet. If you're familiar with the SQL 2000 DTS Packages, you shouldn't have too much difficulty figuring out SSIS packages.